# CakePHP image upload by josegonzalez pulgin

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I am trying to image upload in cakephp by using https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload this plugin.I have almost done upload, now the problem is image directory not sending correctly. Here is the image 
[image]

In controller I have add this code

```
 public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            $data = $this->request->data['User'];
                    if(!$data['photo']['name'])
                            unset($data['photo']);  
                if ($this->User->save($data))  {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The img has been saved.'));

            } else {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__("The img hasn't been saved."));
            }
    }
    }
```

And in add.ctp code is

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Img'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('User.username'); 
        echo $this->Form->input('photo',array('type'=>'file'));
        echo $this->Form->input('User.photo_dir', array('type' => 'hidden')); 
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Here is the user.php model code

```
class User extends AppModel {
     public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'photo' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'photo_dir'
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

photo_dir field type is varchar(255)

photo is uploading webroot\img\upload folder 
How can I send full url in database table?May any body help me please?

Comment: How do you use behavior? did you put the 'dir' => 'photo_dir'? Read https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload#usage

Comment: 'photo' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'photo_dir'
                )
            )
Directory saving but not full directory + image name, only saving id folder.

Comment: I am also having a problem with this. Tsk

Answer (score 0):

Your controller code could look like this:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        $data = $this->request->data['User'];
                if(!$data['photo']['name'])
                        unset($data['photo']);
            $data['photo']['name']='/img/upload/'.$data['photo']['name']  
            if ($this->User->save($data))  {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The img has been saved.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__("The img hasn't been saved."));
        }
    }
}
```

However this isn't actually doing any uploading and it isn't following cake's conventions very strictly.

This is a proper upload (snip-it) without the use of a plugin. Note: this is actual code from a site that kept track of teams.

controller

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Player->create();
        if(isset($this->request->data['Player']['upload'])) {
            foreach($this->request->data['Player']['upload'] as $key => $upload) {
                $file=$upload;
                $path=APP.'webroot/img/Players/'.$file['name'];

                while(file_exists($path)) {
                    $r=rand(1,10000);
                    $file['name']=$r.$file['name'];
                    $path=APP.'webroot/img/Players/'.$file['name'];
                }
                if ($file['error'] == 0) {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path)) {
                        $this->request->data['Player'][$key]='Players/'.$file['name'];;
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something went wrong. Please try again.'));
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($this->Player->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The player has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The player could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        }
    }
    $teams = $this->Player->Team->find('list');
    $ranks = $this->Player->Rank->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('teams', 'ranks'));
}
```

view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Player', array('role' => 'form', 'type' => 'file')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('team_id', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Team Id'));?>               
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('rank_id', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Rank Id'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('upload', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name'));?>
```